# Jenkins Remote Build Scheduler

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, scheduler, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

I am using Jenkins to run automated deployments. For our production servers, approval is required before a deployment job can be initiated. However, the deployment may run at 12:00 AM only.

If I send an *E-mail* with an approval link, the job will kick off ***immediately*** once approved. The only way I am aware of is to ***schedule the job remotely***, appending `&delay=30sec` (or any amount of time) as an URL argument. The problem is how to determine and set the required delay (in seconds), as URL parameter, between the time the email is sent and 12:00 AM when the job starts, without creating another supplementary job? This should depend on the time that it was approved.

Or is there a better approach?

Comment: your question is somewhat obscure. Which time slice you want to embed into job remote trigger?

Comment: I want the build to start at 12:00 AM no matter what time the build is approved. For Ex. if someone request a build at 2:30 PM and it is approved via email at 4:30 PM I still want the build to start at 12:00AM the next moring.

Comment: take a look at [Schedule Build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Schedule+Build+Plugin). It might be able to be you are looking for.
This SO thread my provide some more info as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029486/how-can-i-schedule-a-job-to-run-in-the-future-but-only-one-time-ever

Comment: Yes those are to schedule from the Jenkins UI, I am trying to schedule the job remotely.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I added a schedule string parameter. This parameter accepts the Jenkins version of chron format. I then created a job DSL which will take the schedule variable and place it in the scm() block of code. This will create a new job to do the scheduled processing at the time specified.